# bind hostname to container docker

Tags: docker

I'm tiring to create new docker container like this:

```
docker run -d -p5050:443 --name=free-proxy -v proxy-config:/data -e telegrammessenger/proxy:latest
```

this command successfully created a new container. now i want to restrict this container, to only work with host name not IP address.
 i try this command:

```
docker run -d -ptest.com:5050:443 --name=fourth-proxy -v proxy-config:/data -e telegrammessenger/proxy:latest
```

but i get this error:

```
docker: Invalid ip address: test.com.
```

i just want my container only work with host name (not IP address.)

***NOTE:***
i want to access to my container from outside with just host name.
if the clients use IP address they cant use the proxy:

```
tg://proxy?server=4.2.2.4&port=5050 (not acceptable)
tg://proxy?server=test.com&port=5050 (acceptable)
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in `-ptest.com:5050:443`, it should be `-p5050:443`

Comment: And when you have a running Docker container, you can refer to it inside other containers by using its name which is `fourth-proxy` is your case.

Comment: thanks dear @NeerajWadhwa. but this way container works with IP address too. i want restrict it just host name.

Comment: When you say outside, do you mean from another system on your LAN or just the Docker host?

Comment: dear @NeerajWadhwa I meant other systems on WAN.

Comment: In this case, you might need to set-up a DNS system like `SkyDNSv1/SkyDock`, but I dont't know how Docker will restrict access just by hostname and not IP address as you would need some kind of a mapping with hostname so that Docker knows where to go.

Comment: thanks dear @NeerajWadhwa. you are right. i thought that too. i can run a nginix server and then connect it to my docker container with  127.0.0.1 and then simply handle the outside connections with nginix. but i thought there was a simple solution so i asked the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker publishes ports at the L4 layer, it is not looking at the L7 data that could contain the hostname. The only thing you have when listening on tcp/ip ports is the port number and the network interface (represented by the ip address).

To filter by hostname, you'll need to either place this logic in your application, or setup a proxy in front of your application to do the filtering. There are several reverse proxies that could do this, including traefik, nginx, and haproxy.

Comment: thanks dear @BMitch. would you please provide sample or introduce the article in order to do that?

Comment: I've [previously blogged about a traefik solution](https://boxboat.com/2017/10/10/managing-multiple-microservices-with-traefik-in-docker-swarm/).